# Device Gyroscope(Accelerometer) not working with -ObjC Linker Flag in Cocos2dx-2.2.6

Tags: c++, ios, xcode6, cocos2d-x, 2d-games

I am developing a game in cocos2dx-2.2.6.In this game,there is a player which is moving with acceleration by using the device gyroscope movement.

I am using virtual `didAccelerate(CCAcceleration* pAccelerationValue)` function for this. It is working properly in xcode6.1 with 'blank' "Other linker flag" settings in build settings of my project.

When i add the linker flag `-ObjC` to it for 3rd Party inmobi banner ads integration, my device gyroscope stops working.

I didn't get what i am doing wrong or other settings required with this linker flag in Cocos2dx-2.2.6?

If anybody can, please help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Delete references or comment all lines of code in the two files below:

```
../cocos2dx/platform/ios/Simulation/AccelerometerSimulation.h
../cocos2dx/platform/ios/Simulation/AccelerometerSimulation.m
```

I have tested this and it seems to be working fine.